# How to calculate normal (of magnitude 1) of a triangle?

Tags: matrices, geometry, vector-spaces, triangles

I am currently doing a bit of geometry practice and wanted to know how to calculate the `normal (of magnitude 1) of a triangle` defined by 3 vertices: a, b and c`.

Also, how to calculate the direction for the normal?